# How do you test for memory leaks on the new XCode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just got the new xcode and the tool I used to test for leaks isn't there under run anymore? Can someone tell me how to test for leaks?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having direct instruments in the menu, you start the app using the "profile" option and it asks you which instrument you want to use - there are the instruments you used to see, including Object Alloc and Leaks.  There's also a very useful Zombie tool to help with over-released objects.